# Finding iPhone Unique identifier using a web app

Tags: iphone

I know how to get the unique id of a iPhone/iPod touch from UIDevice. Is there any way to know that from a web app?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible from a web app, cf Apple mailing list answer :

["this would be a privacy violation"](http://lists.apple.com/archives/safari-iphone-web-dev/2009/Jun/msg00016.html)